# Selecting sublist?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two EF types, Study and Patient.  A Study can have many Patients.  I want to return a list of patients from a particular study, so I have a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Patient> GetPatientsByStudyId(int id)
{
    return Context.Studies.Where(e => e.StudyId == id).Select(s => s.Patients).First();
}
```

This works, but it sure looks weird, with that First() call at the end.  I feel like I'm not doing it right.  Is there a clearer or more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like this :

```
public IEnumerable<Patient> GetPatientsByStudyId(int id)
{
    return Context.Studies.Single(e => e.StudyId == id).Patients;
}
```

This will get the desired study, then select all patients related to this study. Of course, you need to make sure that the id parameter is valid. This following code will prevent some unwanted exceptions to occur :

```
public IEnumerable<Patient> GetPatientsByStudyId(int id)
{
    Study selectedStudy = Context.Studies.SingleOrDefault(e => e.StudyId == id);
    return selectedStudy == null ? null : selectedStudy.Patients;
}
```

(or `Enumerable.Empty<Patient>()` instead of `null` if you prefer)

Comment: Actually the query I had does return a list of all patients (there are 4 in my case) so it behaves as expected- but it is that `First()` that confuses things for me.  Also your syntax does not work for me.  There is no `Select()` off `Single()`.  Maybe it's because I'm using EF6?

Comment: I just edited my post, it was indeed a mistake. It should work now. In your initial query, Context.Studies.Where(e => e.StudyId == id).Select(s => s.Patients) gives you a collection of collections of patients, because Select does not flatten collections (unlike SelectMany). Taking the First() element of this query gives you a collection of patient, which is why you still get the requested result.

Comment: This works, thanks for the edit.  The only thing that I had to add was an include for Patients- so `Context.Studies.Include("Patients").Single etc`.  This is because of my EF lazy load settings though.  Thanks!